# Find pickle version installed in my system

Tags: python, pickle

I would like to know pickle version installed in my system.Can someone please tell me what should be the procedure to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Python 2**

```
import pickle 
print pickle.__version__
```

Comment: AttributeError: module 'pickle' has no attribute "__version__"

Comment: Yeah observed the same on my python 3.7.4
I have used `print(pickle.format_version)` and it worked

Comment: apparently this doesn't work anymore, and you must use ````pickle.format_version```` in the recent versions of python.

Answer (score 86):

**Python 3**

```
import pickle 
print(pickle.format_version)
```